# stop script debug error dialogs occur in ie8?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I get this,

[image]

clicking 'no' means the page displays flawlessly.

it's refering to this part of jquery1.4.2.js:

```
// Get the Nth element in the matched element set OR
// Get the whole matched element set as a clean array
get: function( num ) {
    return num == null ?

        // Return a 'clean' array
        this.toArray() :

        // Return just the object
        ( num < 0 ? this.slice(num)[ 0 ] : this[ num ] );
},
```

I assume i'm calling something in the wrong context *somewhere* in one of my js files (which would be a real mission to find).

Will standard IE8 users get this error?

(i imagine ms make it pretty difficult to reinstall ie!)

my javascript:

```
var IE = /*@cc_on!@*/false; 

//DOCUMENT.READY EVENTS
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
$(window).ready(function(){         
    // mark events as not loaded
    $('.event').data({
        t1_loaded: false,
        t2_loaded: false,
        t3_loaded: false,
        art_req: false
    }); 

    //mark no events have been clicked
    $('#wrap_right').data('first_click_made', false);

    //TAB CLICK -> AJAX LOAD TAB
    $('#wrap_right .rs_tabs li').live('click', function(){
        var id = $('#wrap_right').data('curr_event');
        var tab = parseInt($(this).attr('rel'));
        do_tab(id, tab);        
    })

    // cal-block event click
    $('#cal_blocks div.event, #main_search div.event').live('click', function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id').split('e')[1];
        window.location.hash = id;
    });

    // jq history
    $.historyInit(function(hash){
        if(hash){event_load(hash);}
    });

    // search
    $('#search_input').typeWatch
        ({
            callback: function(){
                var q = $('#search_input').attr('value');
                search(q);
            },
            wait : 350,
            highlight : false,
            captureLength : 2
        });     

    $('#search_input, #main_search div.close').live('click',function(){
        $(this).attr("value","");
        reset_srch_res();   
    });

    $('#main_search').easydrag();       
    $('a.dialog').colorbox();

    //artist names in event desc -> scroll
    $('#wrap_right .art_link').live('click', function(){                    
        var art_id = $(this).attr('rel');   
        var id = $('#wrap_right').data('curr_event');
        $('#e'+id).data('art_req', art_id);
        $('#rs_'+id+' .t2').click();        
    });


});


// FUNCTIONS
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

    function event_load(id){
        console.log('function called: event_load');
        //mark current event    
        $('#wrap_right').data('curr_event', id);

        //hide any other events
        if($('#wrap_right').data('first_click_made') === true)
            {
                $('#wrap_right .event_rs').hide();
            }


        //frame loaded before?
        var loaded = $('#e'+id).data('t1_loaded');
        if(loaded === true) {
            $('#rs_'+id).show();        
        }
        else {
            create_frame(id);
        }

        //open/load the first tab
        $('#rs_'+id+' .t1').click();
        $('#cal_blocks').scrollTo('#e'+id, 1000, {offset: {top:-220, left:0}});
    }

    function create_frame(id){
        console.log('function called: create_frame');
        var art = ents[id].art;
        var ven = ents[id].ven;
        var type = ents[id].gig_club;
        var nn = ents[id].nn;   
        var ven_add = ents[id].venue;

        //select colours for tabs
        if(type  == 1){ var label = 'gig';}
        else if(type  == 2){ var label = 'club';}
        else if(type  == 0){ var label = 'other';}

        //create rs container for this event
        var frame =             '<div id="rs_'+id+'" class="event_rs">';
        frame +=                '<div class="title_strip">';
        frame +=                '<p class="rs_nn hf_font">'+nn+'</p><p class="rs_ven">'+ven_add+'</p>';
        frame +=                '</div>';
        frame +=                '<div class="rs_tabs"><ul class="'+label+'"><li class="t1 nav_tab1 curr_tab hand" rel="1"></li>';
        if(art == 1){frame +=   '<li class="t2 nav_tab2 hand" rel="2"></li>';}
        if(ven == 1){frame +=   '<li class="t3 nav_tab2 hand" rel="3"></li>';}
        frame +=                '</ul></div>';
        frame +=                '<div id="rs_content"><div class="tab_body tab1" ></div>';
        if(art == 1){frame +=   '<div class="tab_body tab2"></div>';}
        if(ven == 1){frame +=   '<div class="tab_body tab3"></div>';}
        frame +=                '</div>';
        frame +=                '</div>';
        $('#wrap_right').append(frame); 
    };


    //load or show required tab
    function do_tab(id, tab){
        console.log('function called: do_tab');
        //hide other tabs
        $('#rs_'+id+' .tab_body').hide();   
        //mark current(clicked) tab
        $('#rs_'+id+' .rs_tabs li').removeClass('curr_tab');
        $('#rs_'+id+' .rs_tabs .t'+tab).addClass('curr_tab');

        //is the tab already loaded and hidden?
        var loaded = $('#e'+id).data('t'+tab+'_loaded');
        if(loaded === true)
            {
                $('#rs_'+id+' .tab'+tab).show();
                if (tab == 2) { art_requested(id); }
            }
        else
            {
                //ajax load in the tab
                $('#rs_'+id+' .tab'+tab).load('index_files/tab'+tab+'.php?id='+id, function(){                  
                    //after load callback
                    if (tab == 1)
                        { setup_tab_1(id); }
                    if (tab == 2) { setup_tab_2(id); }                                  
                });
                //mark tab as loaded
                $('#e'+id).data('t'+tab+'_loaded', true);
                //fade in current tab
                $('#rs_'+id+' .tab'+tab).fadeIn(600);           
            }   
    }


    //mark current event in cal-blocks  
    function mark_current(id){
        console.log('function called: mark_current');
        $('#cal_blocks .event_sel').removeClass('event_sel');
        $('#e'+id).addClass('event_sel');
    }


    //setup tab 1   
    function setup_tab_1(id){
        console.log('function called: setup_tab_1');    
        $('#rs_' + id + ' .frame').fadeIn(600);

        var $img = $('#rs_'+id+' .event_img');
        var rel = $img.attr('rel');
        if (rel !== '')
            {
                $img.live('click', function(){
                    $.fn.colorbox({href: rel, overlayClose: true});
                });
            }

        if($('#wrap_right').data('first_click_made') === false)
            {
                //$('#wrap_right').delay(500).slideDown();
                //$('#rs_'+id+' .rs_tabs').delay(800).fadeIn(600);
                load_fb_js();
                $('#wrap_right').data('first_click_made', true);
            }
        mark_current(id);
    }

    //setup tab 2
    function setup_tab_2(id) {
        console.log('function called: setup_tab_2');
        art_requested(id);
        $('#rs_'+id+' #art_scrollable').scrollable({
            size: 1,
            easing: 'swing',
            clickable: false,
            onBeforeSeek: function(){before();},
            onSeek: function(){after();}
        }).navigator("#art_scroll_nav");
        prep_media_carousel();  
    }



    //check to see if an artist has been requested
    function art_requested(id){
        console.log('function called: art_requested');
        var art_req = $('#e'+id).data('art_req');   
        if(art_req !== false)
            {
                $('#art_'+art_req).click();
            }
    }


    //scroll artist panes smoothly (scroll bars cause glitches otherwise)

    function before (){ 
        if(!IE){$('#art_scrollable .bio_etc').css('overflow','-moz-scrollbars-none');}
    }

    function after (){          
        if(!IE){$('#art_scrollable .bio_etc').css('overflow','auto');}
    }


    // MEDIA CAROUSEL 
    //--------------------------

    function prep_media_carousel(){
        console.log('function called: prep_media_carousel');
        //youtube and soundcloud player
        $("#rs_content .yt_scrollable a.yt, #rs_content .yt_scrollable a.sc").colorbox({                
            overlayClose : false,
            opacity : 0
        });     

        $("#colorbox").easydrag(true);
        $('#cboxOverlay').remove();
    }


    function make_carousel_scrollable(unique_id){
        console.log('function called: make_carousel_scrollable');   
        $('#scroll_'+unique_id).scrollable({
            size:1,
            clickable:false,
            nextPage:'#r_'+unique_id,
            prevPage:'#l_'+unique_id
        });
    }


    function check_l_r_arrows(total, counter, art_id){
        console.log('function called: check_l_r_arrows');
        //left arrow
        if(counter > 0)
            {
                $('#l_'+art_id).show();
                $('#l_'+art_id+'_inactive').hide();
            }
        else
            {
                $('#l_'+art_id).hide();
                $('#l_'+art_id+'_inactive').show();
            }

        //right arrow   
        if(counter < total-3)
            {
                $('#r_'+art_id).show();
                $('#r_'+art_id+'_inactive').hide();
            }
        else
            {
                $('#r_'+art_id).hide();
                $('#r_'+art_id+'_inactive').show();
            }
    }



    //load facebook scripts
    function load_fb_js(){
        console.log('function called: load_fb_js');
        $.getScript('http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/connect.php/en_GB', function(){
            //callback
            FB.init("89bb37189bede9e30eb07a66b9a1c52a");
        });
    }


    // SEARCH
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    function reset_srch_res(){
        $('#main_search').fadeOut(400).children().remove();
    }

    function search(q){
            console.log('function called: search');
            $.ajax({  
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'index_files/srch/search.php?q='+q,
                success: function(e)
                    {
                        $('#main_search').html(e).show();           
                    }  
            }); 
    }
```

Comment: Are you using `:nth-child()` or any other position selectors anywhere in your code?

Comment: not that i can think of... have pasted code above

Comment: ok i've fixed it - was the facebook connect script.

still curious about what kind of errors normal/non developer users get..

Comment: Those errors don't depend on you being a "developer" or having Visual Studio installed. A former employer would regularly tell customers to enable error reporting when we had to diagnose problems, so you should expect that anybody might see those. Even if the diagnostic dialogs are disabled, the page still reports when there are errors, so you really shouldn't ignore them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They'll get a little yellow icon in the bottom, or else they'll see exactly what you see, depending on the way the browser is set up. I suspect that, in some way, your page is *not* without flaw. You should be able to use the developer tools to check a stack trace and figure out where in your code the error is happening. Alternatively, you can bracket code with try/catch blocks and seek out the error that way.

[edit] Here's what the browser shows, in the lower left corner:
[image]
<sub>(source: [gutfullofbeer.net](http://gutfullofbeer.net/err.png))</sub>

Double-clicking on that brings up the same error dialog you see.